# Problema con condicion if en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar mi codigo ya que la idea es que cuando un producto ya este registrado solo se pueda ingresar la cantidad y precio, sin embargo al ingresar la misma clave de producto en lugar de que salga eso me permite cambiar el nombre del producto(lo cual no debe suceder ya que esa clave de producto solo puede tener un nombre)  yaesta es para la clave del proovedor y yaesta2= clave del producto

```js
if(menu==2){
  yaesta=0;
  yaesta2=0;
proveedor1=prompt("Ingrese ID del proveedor")
for(x=1;x<=renglon;x++){
  if(proveedor1===clave[x])
  {
    yaesta=1;
  }
}
if(yaesta===0){
  alert("No se encontró ID")
}

if(yaesta===1)  {
  producto1=prompt("Ingrese clave del producto uwu")

  for(x=1;x<100;x++)
  {
    if(producto1=producto[x])
    {
      yaesta2=1; 
       
    }
  }
}
if(yaesta2===1 && yaesta===1){
  alert("Producto encontrado: "+producto[x]);
  producto[x]=prompt("Ingrese precio de "+producto[x]);
  cantidad[x]=prompt("Ingrese cantidad de "+ producto[x]);
}
if(yaesta2===0 && yaesta===1){
  producto[x]=prompt("Ingrese nombre del producto")
  precio[x]=prompt("Ingrese precio del producto")
  cantidad[x]=prompt("Ingrese cantidad de producto")
}
  
}//Adquisiciones
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: He mirado el codigo mas a fondo, y he encontrado unos cuantos fallos.
Los arrays se recorren desde la posicion 0 y no 1
Para recorrer los arrays, usa length para controlar si llega al final.
Una vez encontrado el valor, no hace falta seguir buscando.
Para comparar se usa '==' y no '=' ('===' es para comprobar que sea el mismo valor y tipo, se debería usar solo en casos concretos)
Comparas el identificador de producto con el nombre del producto, por eso no lo encontraba.
Una vez introducido el indicador, hay que guardarlo para futuras comprobaciones.
El precio lo estas guardando en producto[x] y no en precio[x]
He retocado un poco el código para que puedas probarlo desde aquí.

```js
/* Me invento variables */
 var clave=["1","2","3","4","5"];
 var claveProducto=[]; // array inventada, no se cual usas.
 var producto=[];
 var precio=[];
 var cantidad=[];
/* ********************* */
do {  // Me invento que repite hasta poner un 0 para poder salir.
 yaesta=0;
 yaesta2=0;
 proveedor1=prompt("Ingrese ID del proveedor (0 para salir)");
 if (proveedor1!="0") {
  for(x=0 ; x<clave.length ; x++){ // primer fallo, los arrays se inician en la posicion 0, para recorrer todo el array usa length.
   if(proveedor1===clave[x])
   {
    yaesta=1;
    break; // consejo, una vez encontrado no hace falta seguir buscando.
   }
  }
  if(yaesta===0){
   alert("No se encontró ID")
  }
  if(yaesta===1)  {
   producto1=prompt("Ingrese clave del producto uwu")
   for(x=0 ; x<claveProducto.length ; x++)// Los arrays se inician en la posicion 0, para recorrer todo el array usa length.
   {
    if(producto1==claveProducto[x]) // fallo, para comparar se una '=='
    {        // fallo, estas comparando una "clave" con producto[x] y deberia ser claveProducto[x] (o donde tu lo tengas)
     yaesta2=1; 
     break; // consejo, una vez encontrado no hace falta seguir buscando.
    }
   }
  }
  if(yaesta2===1 && yaesta===1){
   alert("Producto encontrado: "+producto[x]);
   precio[x]=prompt("Ingrese precio de "+producto[x]); // fallo, el precio deberia ir a precio[x]
   cantidad[x]=prompt("Ingrese cantidad de "+ producto[x]);
  }
  if(yaesta2===0 && yaesta===1){
   claveProducto[x]=producto1; // si no existe la id de producto, lo incluye.
   producto[x]=prompt("Ingrese nombre del producto")
   precio[x]=prompt("Ingrese precio del producto")
   cantidad[x]=prompt("Ingrese cantidad de producto")
  }
 }
} while (proveedor1!=0)
```

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo.

Comment: ya lo hice asi, sin embargo sigue ocurriendo lo mismo

Comment: He editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando hagas una comparación de strings asegurate de parsear el contenido utilizando

```
if(String("producto1") == String("producto2"))
```

toma también en cuenta la diferencia entre operadores

```
if(a===a)
```

es diferente a:

`if(a==a)`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este codigo no se si era lo que querias pero espero y te sirva. Lo ordene un poco para tener una mejor organizacion de los productos.

```js
// Proveedores de los productos 
let provedores = [[], [], [], [], []]
// Productos
let productos = []

let yaesta = 0
let yaesta2 = 0

do {
  // Almacena el id del proveedor donde se van almacenar los productos
  let proveedorID = prompt("Ingrese ID del proveedor (0 para salir)")
  
  if(proveedorID == 0) break
    
  // Identifica si existe el proveedor
  if(provedores[proveedorID] === undefined){
    // Si no existe te pide que crees uno nuevo.
    if(confirm("No se encontro el ID del provedor. ¿Decea crear uno nuevo?")){
      proveedorID = provedores.length + 1
      provedores[proveedorID-1] = []
      yaesta = 1
    }
  } else {
    yaesta = 1
  }

  if(yaesta == 0) {
    alert("No se encontro el ID")
  } else if(yaesta == 1) {
    
    // Verifica si el array de productos y el de proveedor ya cuenta con productos.
    if(productos.length && provedores[proveedorID-1].length){
    
      let claveProducto = prompt("Ingrese clave del producto")
      
      // Iteramos en el array de productos en el proveedor elegido para saber si la clave obtenida ya existe en un producto. 
      provedores[proveedorID-1].every(producto => {
      
        if(claveProducto == producto.key){
          yaesta2 = 1
          alert("producto encontrado: " + producto.nombre)
          producto.precio = prompt("Ingrese precio del producto " + producto.nombre)
          producto.cantidad = prompt("Ingrese cantidad del producto " + producto.nombre)
          
          return false

        }
        
        return true
      })
      
      if(yaesta2 == 0) create(claveProducto)
      
    } else {
      // Si no crea uno nuevo desde cero.
      create(1)
    }
  }
  
  // Crea nuevos productos.
  function create(keyInit){
    const newProduct = {
      key: keyInit,
      proveedor: proveedorID,
      nombre: prompt("Ingrese nombre del producto"),
      precio: prompt("Ingrese precio del producto"),
      cantidad: prompt("Ingrese cantidad del producto")
    }

    productos.push(newProduct)
    provedores[proveedorID-1].push(newProduct)
  }
  
} while(true)

console.log("Todos los productos: ")
console.log(productos)
console.log("Proveedores: ")
console.log(provedores)
```